# Tidiest way to create Excel formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I've been working on this Excel spreadsheet and the main formula is the one below. Pretty simple but I've been trying to get it to work with an HTML form input field in Javascript. Basically, the user needs to be able to put a number into the field and it displays the relevant percentage, depending on that number- using Javascript.

```
If less than or equal to 5000 it will display 10%
If greater than 5000 but less than or equal to 10000 it will display 20%
If greater than 10000 it will display 30%
```

```
=IF(AND(B2<=5000),10%,IF(AND(B2>5000,B2<=10000),20%,IF(AND(B2>10000),30%)))
```

I'd made a couple of starts at it but got rid of them as there must be a simpler way of doing this.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
=IF(B2>10000, 30%, IF(B2>5000,20%,10%))
```

if using jQuery...

```
$('#button').change(function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val());
if(n > 10000) {
     $('.output').val('30%');
}
else if(n > 5000) {
     $('.output').val('20%');
else {
     $('.output').val('10%');
}
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LC2uJ/

Comment: Thanks @waplet I just made an edit as I realised I didn't really put the main point in my question. What I'm actually looking for is the tidiest way to rewrite the formula in Javascript.

Comment: Ye, it took a while to understand it :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple conversion of your logic:

```
function getPercentValue(num){
    if(num<=5000){
        return (10/100); //10%
    }else if(num>5000 && num<=1000){
        return (20/100); //20%
    }else if(num>10000){
        return (30/100); //30%;
    }
}

getPercentValue(450); --> 10%
getPercentValue(5487); --> 20%
getPercentValue(15700); --> 30%
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
var res = b2 <= 5000 ? '10%' : (b2 <= 10000 ? '20%' : '30%');
```